# Is there a Widget in Flutter that is disabled after a specified timeout?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder if there is some kind of widget that fades out as soon as some time passes.

Something like that:

```dart
child: Temporary(500, child: Text("I will disappear in 500ms"))
```

If it does not exist in a package or build-in yet - what would be a good way to solve this by myself?

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the `AnimatedOpacity` widget.

There is a cookbook with detailed description. But instead of using a button to toggle the visibility, you could make use of a `Timer()` call which fires once, has a Duration set to 500 ms and a callback that changes the visibility boolean.

The link:

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/opacity-animation